How does one work with an adventure Seed in the format of "Challenge-Focus-Strike"?
Legends of the 5 Rings has an established format to pitch "adventure seeds". Those are not fully formed adventures but guidelines to build an adventure around, akin to a writing prompt. They generally contain a problem, a complication, and a (hint of) a showdown for an adventure in three lines captioned as "Challenge Focus Strike". Those are also the phases of an Iaijutsu Duel under the L5R rules since at least 3rd edition.
There are podcasts and on kaze-no-shiro a whole document series dedicated to this format of adventure seeds, and one might read something like this:

Challenge: People get attacked at the crossroads of Imperial Road 12 and the path to the local fortress at night.
Focus: A surviving Heimin tells about a person wearing a straw basket over the head while yelling something about his new blade.
Strike: Taking the road at night, the samurai face off against what seems to be a Ronin in the act of Tsujigiri! But during the fight, it turns out to be Konda-sensei, a teacher at the local Dojo, out to try and kill an elusive student who sold out the school's secrets!

Sure, it's a seed, but this opens two closely related questions:

What guidelines exist for writing a seed using the Challenge Focus Strike method?
How do you turn the seed into an adventure that is ready for the group?

